# How do I delete the gems associated with a rvm ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I've done `rvm remove` on a Ruby, but the gems still remain:

```
$ rvm remove ruby-1.8.7-head
Removing /Users/agrimm/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-head...
Removing /Users/agrimm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-head aliases...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-head wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-head environments...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-head binaries...

$ ls /Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems | grep 1.8.7
ruby-1.8.7-head
ruby-1.8.7-head@global
```

I'm doing this because there's a failed gem installation attempt that I want to nuke, but conventional attempts have failed:

```
$ gem install pkg/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gem 
Fetching: ripper-plus-1.3.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: axiom_of_choice-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: stream-0.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: object_regex-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: trollop-1.16.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ripper-plus-1.3.0
Successfully installed axiom_of_choice-1.0.0
Successfully installed stream-0.5
Successfully installed object_regex-1.0.1
Successfully installed trollop-1.16.2
Successfully installed laser-0.7.0.pre2
6 gems installed
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _capi_get_constant
  Referenced from: /Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/json-1.7.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _capi_get_constant
  Referenced from: /Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/json-1.7.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

f8-1e-df-dc-3b-2a:laser agrimm$ gem install pkg/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gem 
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x1046be400> 0.5"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x1046be400> 0.5"]
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed laser-0.7.0.pre2
1 gem installed
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _capi_get_constant
  Referenced from: /Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/json-1.7.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _capi_get_constant
  Referenced from: /Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/json-1.7.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

$ gem list laser
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x104eb6838> 0.5"]

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x104eb6838> 0.5"]

$ gem uninstall laser
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x104eb6838> 0.5"]
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x104eb6838> 0.5"]
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d laser`

$ gem list -d laser
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x104eb6838> 0.5"]

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

Invalid gemspec in [/Users/agrimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/specifications/laser-0.7.0.pre2.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x104eb6838> 0.5"]

$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the [--gems](https://rvm.io/rubies/removing/) flag when removing the Ruby if you want to remove the gemsets (and gems) as well. With the Ruby already gone, it looks like you'll have to do it by hand.

Comment: I reinstalled it, then did `rvm remove --gems ruby-1.8.7-head` and it did the trick.

Comment: rvm by default keeps the gem so the `rvm reinstall` works properly ... but I guess I could change it to remove the gems if not called by `rvm requirements`, open a ticket so I can fix it (change behavior) for next release